# How to add amounts from an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays like so...

```
a1 = [[9, -1811.4], [8, 959.86], [7, -385], [6, -1731.39], [5, 806.78], [4, 2191.65]]
```

I need to get the average of the 2nd items(the amounts) from the total array.

So add -1811.4,959.86,-385,-1731.39,806.78 divided by the count (6)

I have tried...

```
a1.inject{ |month, amount| amount }.to_f / a1.size
```

This is not right and I cant see what I need to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a1.map(&:last).inject(:+) / a1.size.to_f
#=> 5.0833333333332575
```

Steps:

```
# 1. select last elements
a1.map(&:last)
#=> [-1811.4, 959.86, -385, -1731.39, 806.78, 2191.65]
# 2. sum them up
a1.map(&:last).inject(:+)
#=> 30.499999999999545
# 3. divide by the size of a1
a1.map(&:last).inject(:+) / a1.size.to_f
#5.0833333333332575
```

Comment: Does this method turn negatives to positives when adding?

Comment: @SupremeA it does not. It just sums it. Do you need to sum absolute values?

Comment: yep I see now Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One pass through `a1` is sufficient.

```
a1.reduce(0) { |tot, (_,b)| tot + b }/a1.size.to_f
  #=> 5.0833333333332575
```

`.to_f` allows `a1` to contain only integer values.

The steps:

```
tot = a1.reduce(0) { |tot, (_,b)| tot + b }
  #=> 30.499999999999545 
n = a1.size.to_f
  #=> 6.0 
tot/n
  #=> 5.0833333333332575
```

Comment: Just another option, we can also use `.fdiv(a1.size)` instead of `/a1.size.to_f`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I'd never heard of [Numeric#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Was also considering adding a `inject` option, but it took  more letters to type then my original one, so i dropped it :)